# How to tell push to avoid appending duplicates value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to avoid `b.push(a);` to add duplicates when b was empty (b = []) or had value as below?

```
var a = ["username1", "1"];
var b = [ ["username1", "1"], ["username2", "2"] ];
b.push(a);
```

Comment: check it before pushing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `some()` and `every()` first to check if `a` exists in `b` and then use push.

```js
var a = ["username1", "1"];
var b = [ ["username1", "1"], ["username2", "2"] ];

var check = b.some(function(e) {
  return a.length == e.length && a.every(function(c) {
    return e.includes(c)
  })
})

if (!check) b.push(a);
console.log(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way of preventing duplicates, you should check for them yourself.

Check the snippet:

```
var a = ["username1", "1"];
var b = [ a, ["username2", "2"] ];

if(b.find(function(element) { return element == a })) {
   b.push(a);
}
```

If record in `b` array has different identity, you should check for values inside it.

You can do it as follow:

```
var a = ["username1", "1"];
var b = [ ["username1", "1"], ["username2", "2"] ];

if(b.find(function(element) { return element[0] == a[0] })) {
   b.push(a);
}
```

Comment: this won't work, because `==` also checks for identity, not for equality when comparing two objects.

Comment: You are right, in this case `a` should be inside `b` array. I just updated my answer for case you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

Convert into JSON string and compare arrays.

```js
var a = ["username1", "1"];
var a1 = ["username3", "1"];
var b = [
  ["username1", "1"],
  ["username2", "2"]
];

Array.prototype.pushCustom = function(item) {
  if (this.every(function(v) {
    return JSON.stringify(v) != JSON.stringify(item);
  }))
    this.push(item);
};

b.pushCustom(a);
b.pushCustom(a1);

console.log(b);
```